# How to install esl-erlang, erlang-crypto, and erlang-tools?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elixir

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed Elixir like so

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
sudo apt-get install elixir
```

When I ran my tests, I got

```
function :crypto.mpint/1 is undefined or private
```

So I installed erlang-crypto like so

```
sudo apt-get install erlang-crypto
```

Then I ran my tests and got

```
no case clause matching: {:error, {:undef, [{:cover, :is_compiled, [:hackney], []}
```

So I installed erlang-tools like so

```
sudo apt-get install erlang-tools
```

But now I get this error again!

```
function :crypto.mpint/1 is undefined or private
```

My guess is these commands are flip flopping me between esl-erlang and the regular erlang, but I'm not sure.

The suspicious line was when I installed erlang-crypto, it said it would remove esl-erlang and install erlang-base!

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools
Suggested packages:
  erlang erlang-manpages erlang-doc erlang-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  esl-erlang
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools
```

How can I have esl-erlang, erlang-crypto, and erlang-tools all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to work around my problem by using [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf). I installed asdf and ran the following commands

```
asdf plugin-add erlang https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang.git
asdf plugin-add elixir https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir.git
sudo apt-get install automake autoconf libreadline-dev libncurses-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev libtool unixodbc-dev
asdf install erlang 19.3
asdf install elixir 1.3.4
asdf global erlang 19.3
asdf global elixir 1.3.4
rm -rf _build/
rm -rf deps/
mix deps.get
mix test
```